# install apache sanselan android studio

Tags: android, android-library

I download the Binaries from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/download_sanselan.cgi and add to the lib folder.but still i have errors.how to install it?

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following line to you dependencies in your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile "org.apache.sanselan:sanselan:0.97-incubator"
  ...
}
```